# Error in using merge function to combine information from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes.

First one in this format, let's call this df

```
Date  Counterparty Amount
3/1   Bank A       $100
3/1   Bank B       $100 
3/1   Bank C       $100
...
3/30  Bank B       $100
3/30  Bank C       $150
3/30  Bank D       $300
3/30  Bank E       $250
```

The second one has rating information for each bank in this format.
Let's call it NRSRO

```
Date  Bank A   Bank B   Bank C   Bank D   Bank E   Bank F ....Bank Z
3/1   AA      ...
3/2   AA      ...
3/3   AA      ...
```

I have tried following code

```
NRSRO= pd.DataFrame(NRSRO.stack(), columns=['Rating']).reset_index()
NRSRO= NRSRO.rename(columns = {'level_1':'Counterparty'})
```

This turns NRSRO dataframe into:

```
Date  Counterparty Rating
3/1   Bank A       AA
3/2   Bank A       AA
...
3/30  Bank A       AA
3/1   Bank B       AAA
3/2   Bank B       AAA
...
...
3/30  Bank Z       AAA
```

Finally, merge to dataframes with

```
result = pd.merge(df, NRSRO, how = 'left', on = ['Date', 'Counterparty'])
```

I'm getting mixed results.

When I run this, return is true.

```
result['Rating'].isnull().values.any()
```

For some banks, I have the ratings data successfully appended to 'result' dataframe, but for others, it shows NaN. I'm confident about data integrity, there's no missing data from the source.

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: Check with pandas. melt

Comment: you mean melt can substitute stack()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joining on two columns with a left join so if NRSRO dataframe has no rating  for Bank A on a particular date and that date is present in `df`, it will be a null in the `result` dataframe. To check if this is happening, run

```
result = pd.merge(df, NRSRO, how = 'inner', on = ['Date', 'Counterparty'])
```

If there are still null values in this dataframe, then there might some nulls in your NRSRO dataframe so you should inspect that. If this returns a perfect dataframe with no nulls, then my above reasoning is true of having some missing data.

Comment: I used left join because I wish to keep df intact. It's fine if there's no rating for a specific bank on a particular data. After checking my data, I found that with NRSRO having the data for Bank A on certain dates, it still shows NaN in result.

Comment: try to join some of the rows which are causing the problem separately. To figure out the solution, we need to debug to get the problem. It could be a date issue in NRSRO that it results in a non-match. Try to join some of them to figure out the problem.

Comment: Great debug advice. I found a space after one of the counterparties that's giving me problems. I'll go fix that and I hope the rest are similar problems. Thanks!